# perform change code in a foreach halfway through iterations

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to create a php foreach statement that outputs different code for the first 5 iterations, and then does a different output for the rest.

I found this snippet, which does a break at a given limit, but how could I continue from the last iteration on another foreach loop?  That's probably not the best way to do it anyways.

```
 $i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    /* Do stuff */
    if (++$i == 2) break;
}
```

Is this possible?  How would I go about it?

Thanks!
Zeem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_slice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) for this:

```
foreach (array_slice($arr, 0, 5, true) as $k => $v) {
    /* Do stuff 1-5 */
}
foreach (array_slice($arr, 5, null, true) as $k => $v) {
    /* Do stuff 6-end */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you look for something like...?

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($var as $k => $v) {
    if ($i < 5) {
        // do something here for the first five iterations
    }
    else {
        // do something else here for further iterations
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($i < 5) { 
        /* do stuff */
    } else { 
        /* other stuff */
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the assumption your array isn't associative, and thereforce $k will be the numeric index. If not the case you'll need your $i.

```
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if ($k < 5) {
        Do stuff
    } else {
        Do other stuff
    }
}
```